# Can't install VS 2015 Update 3

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, installation

So I tried to install VS 2015 Update 3. BTW, I have the professional edition and I  keep receiving this screen:

[image: Screen shot of installation]

Now, of course, Update 2 is already installed but it will not recognize this.

What do I need to do?

Answer (score 54):

Go to `control panel->program and features` select the `Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 Professional with Updates` entry and select `Modify`. Now the Visual Studio 2015 installer shows up and here you should see the Update 3.

Comment: TOTALLY WORKED!! Thanks! :)

Comment: I had this issue with the update 2 and used it there. For the update 3, the downlaoded installer worked again

Comment: I got this problem with my windows 10 machine at home, but my windows 7 machine at the office gave me no issues.

Comment: yes, I approved the edit

Comment: I have VS 2015 Enterprise Update 1 but I see no Update 3 available when I go via the above answer steps. Any other alternatives?

Comment: @Maninder get the Update 3 ISO, mount the ISO and run setup.exe: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=708984

Comment: Hi, i'm trying to install Visual Studio 2015 Update 3. i downloaded the ISO file but every time i run it. my already installed Express 2015 for Windows Desktop appears instead. what do i need to with this? Thanks

Comment: @Binsoi try the step from my answer, open control panel and here select the VS entry and select **Modify**

Comment: @magicandre1981 i tried it, there is no Modify option on Change. it brought me Visual studio setup. did not see anything. So, i uninstalled the VS 2015 Express. and tried to install it. but it lead me to an Error that i should have an existing VS 2015 Family. i cancelled it and installed a different edition. Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition and everything is OK now. Thanks BTW