# I cant install Visual Studio 2015 Update 3

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, installation

On modifying VS from control panel I get the below screen[image].

But when I check program and features I see that my VS Version number is 14.0.23.107.178.[image]

Also I found that these are VS2015 Version nos [image]

meaning mine is currently without update1.
I tried updating from VS2015 modify itself from programs and features as per this Solution [Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38079986/cant-install-vs-2015-update-3)

Comment: What does Help->About  from within Visual Studio show  - that's what counts ? I think the version number shown in "program and features"  is just showing the version number when you installed Visual Studio , not any updates applied  after that.

Comment: Hi JinsPeter, sometimes, the version number that your seen under Programs and Features are not the really one, please go to Help>About Microsoft Visual Studio to check the version, if it is not the latest one: 14.0.25431.01 Update 3, please try to download the VS professional 2015 with update 3 to install the update 3, access this: https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/older-downloads/ and sign in with your Microsoft account and join Visual Studio Dev Essentials, then click ‘Downloads’ and search with ‘Visual Studio Professional 2015 with Update 3’, you can select the .exe or ISO to download.

Comment: Hi Thank you guys.. It correct in About VS

Comment: @JinsPeter, I'm so glad to hear that your issue solved and you can add a reply with this solution, then you mark it as answer and that will help other community members to easier search this information. Or I add a reply and you can mark it when you have free time, ok?

Comment: @Sara-MSFT Thanks. Done that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the commenters, I got answer to this. As a matter of fact, the VS2015 has already been updated and that was why I couldn't Update it again.
Only issue is OS won't always shows the updated version number in `Control Panel ->'Programs and Features'`. It shows the version number when VS was installed.
The actual updated VS Version number can be seen using `VS-> Help-> About Visual Studio`.